# counting the number of strings in a text file containing numbers as well

Tags: c, string, file

I wanted to only count the number of strings in a text file, containing numbers as well. But the code below, counts even the numbers in the file as strings. How do I rectify the problem?

```
int count;
char *temp;
FILE *fp;

 fp = fopen("multiplexyz.txt" ,"r" );

 while(fscanf(fp,"%s",temp) != EOF )
 {
     count++;
 }

 printf("%d ",count);
 return 0;
```

}

Comment: can you give an example, of the input file, actual output and expected output.

Comment: String is a set of words. So if your file has just 1 word which is a pure number {3422} like `this is nub1234 3422 hello rock` then what's the count you are expecting?

Comment: I am trying to count the number of pure strings. In my input there are NO mixed letters and numbers. For the given input the output expected : 4 { this,is,hello,rock}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, first up, using the `temp` pointer without having backing storage for it is going to cause you a world of pain.

I'd suggest, as a start, using something like `char temp[1000]` instead, keeping in mind that's still a bit risky if you have words more than a thousand or so characters long (that's a *different* issue to the one you're asking about so I'll mention it but not spend *too* much time on fixing it).

Secondly, it appears you want to count words with numbers (like `alpha7` or `pi/2`). If that's the case, you simply need to check `temp` after reading the "word" and increment `count` only if it matches a "non-numeric" pattern.

That *could* be as simple as just not incrementing if the word consists only of digits, or it could be complicated if you want to handle decimals, exponential formats and so on.

But the bottom line remains the same:

```
while(fscanf(fp,"%s",temp) != EOF )
{
    if (! isANumber(temp))
        count++;
}
```

with a suitable definition of `isANumber`. For example, for unsigned integers only, something like this would be a good start:

```
int isANumber (char *str) {
    // Empty string is not a number.

    if (*str == '\0')
        return 0;

    // Check every character.

    while (*str != '\0') {
        // If non-digit, it's not a number.

        if (! isdigit (*str))
            return 0;
        str++;
    }

    // If all characters were digits, it was a number.

    return 1;
}
```

For more complex checking, you can use the `strto*` calls in C, giving them the `temp` buffer and ensuring you use the `endptr` method to ensure the entire string is scanned. Off the top of my head, so not *well* tested, that would go something like:

```
int isANumber (char *str) {
    // Empty string is not a number.

    if (*str == '\0')
        return 0;

    // Use strtod to get a double.

    char *endPtr;
    long double d = strtold (str, &endPtr);

    // Characters unconsumed, not number (things like 42b).

    if (*endPtr != '\0')
        return 0;

    // Was a long double, so number.

    return 1;
}
```

The only thing you need to watch out for there is that certain strings like `NaN` or `+Inf` are considered a number by `strtold` so you may need extra checks for that.

Answer (score 0):

inside your while loop, loop through the string to check if any of its characters are digits. Something like:

```
while(*temp != '\0'){
       if(isnumber(*temp))
           break;
}
```

[dont copy exact same code]

Answer (score 0):

I find `strpbrk` to be one of the most helpful function to search for several *needles* in a *haystack*. Your set of *needles* being the numeric characters `"0123456789"` which if present in a line read from your file will count as a line. I also prefer POSIX `getline` for a line count do to its proper handling of files with non-POSIX line endings for the last line (both `fgets` and `wc -l` omit text (and a count) of the last line if it does not contain a POSIX line end (`'\n'`).  That said, a small function that searches a line for characters contained in a `trm` passed as a parameter could be written as:

```
/** open and read each line in 'fn' returning the number of lines
 *  continaing any of the characters in 'trm'.
 */
size_t nlines (char *fn, char *trm)
{
    if (!fn) return 0;

    size_t lines = 0, n = 0;
    char *buf = NULL;
    FILE *fp = fopen (fn, "r");

    if (!fp) return 0;

    while (getline (&buf, &n, fp) != -1)
        if (strpbrk (buf, trm))
            lines++;

    fclose (fp);
    free (buf);

    return lines;
}
```

Simply pass the filename of interest and the terms to search for in each line. A short test code with a default term of `"0123456789"` that takes the filename as the first parameter and the term as the second could be written as follows:

```
#include <stdio.h>      /* printf */
#include <stdlib.h>     /* free   */
#include <string.h>     /* strlen, strrchr */

size_t nlines (char *fn, char *trm);

int main (int argc, char **argv) {

    char *fn   = argc > 1 ? argv[1] : NULL;
    char *srch = argc > 2 ? argv[2] : "0123456789";
    if (!fn) return 1;

    printf ("%zu %s\n", nlines (fn, srch), fn);

    return 0;
}

/** open and read each line in 'fn' returning the number of lines
 *  continaing any of the characters in 'trm'.
 */
size_t nlines (char *fn, char *trm)
{
    if (!fn) return 0;

    size_t lines = 0, n = 0;
    char *buf = NULL;
    FILE *fp = fopen (fn, "r");

    if (!fp) return 0;

    while (getline (&buf, &n, fp) != -1)
        if (strpbrk (buf, trm))
            lines++;

    fclose (fp);
    free (buf);

    return lines;
}
```

Give it a try and see if this is what you are expecting, if not, just let me know and I am glad to help further.

**Example Input File**

```
$ cat dat/linewno.txt
The quick brown fox
jumps over 3 lazy dogs
who sleep in the sun
with a temp of 101
```

**Example Use/Output**

```
$ ./bin/getline_nlines_nums dat/linewno.txt
2 dat/linewno.txt

$ wc -l dat/linewno.txt
4 dat/linewno.txt
```

Comment: The behaviour of `wc` regarding lines is *arguably* correct if you define a line as zero or more characters terminated with a newline character (i.e., a complete line). In addition, consider the case where you had two such files `a` and `b`. If you consider the last non-newlined line to be an actual line then the sum of the line count of the individuals files (`wc -l <a` plus `wc -l <b`) is not equal to the line count of the files joined together (`cat a b | wc -l`). Not saying your way is either right *or* wrong, just that it's nuanced. In any case, it doesn't affect the core of your answer.

Comment: And, since I was curious, I checked the man page to see what was intended. It quite explicitly states for `-l`: `print the newline counts`.  So, whether you agree with the behaviour or not, it's working exactly as specified. Maybe we should raise a feature request for `--lines-including-final-possibly-non-terminated-one` :-)

Comment: Yes, it is a curious choice made in how `wc -l` reports lines. I guess that is why we have a definition for a POSIX line ending. An equally interesting revelation is snapping to why `while (fgets (...))` and `while (getline (...) != -1)` report the number of lines differently depending on the POSIX line ending. It's so obvious it smacks you in the face, but that doesn't prevent scratching your head for a few minutes before the light-bulb winks on (at least for me).